# How to make advanced filter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel

**The Question;**
I want to filter by properties.

I have json data coming from the api and I want to filter that data.(If there is a way to do with laravel I would like to try that too)

**Json Data;**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Deneme Batarya",
    "description": "<p>Deneme Batarya</p>",
    "slug": "deneme-batarya",
    "brand_id": 4,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:02",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:02",
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "Giyilebilir Teknoloji",
        "description": null,
        "slug": "giyilebilir-teknoloji",
        "media": "public/media/slider/ms-10.jpg",
        "level": 0,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
          "product_id": 1,
          "category_id": 3
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "parent_id": 3,
        "title": "Akıllı Bileklik",
        "description": null,
        "slug": "akilli-bileklik",
        "media": "public/media/slider/ms-10.jpg",
        "level": 2,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
          "product_id": 1,
          "category_id": 26
        }
      }
    ],
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 1,
        "sku": "model-45b",
        "image": "public/media/product/1-model-45b864.png",
        "level": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:49:16",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:49:16"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": null,
        "sku": null,
        "image": "public/media/product/1--501.jpeg",
        "level": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:53:27",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:53:27"
      }
    ],
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "qty": 5,
        "status": "Available",
        "price": "56.00",
        "discount": 5,
        "sku": "model-45b",
        "start": "2021-02-22 00:00:00",
        "end": "2021-02-23 00:00:00",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "product_id": 1,
        "qty": 6,
        "status": "Available",
        "price": "90.00",
        "discount": 4,
        "sku": "model-45a",
        "start": "2021-02-25 00:00:00",
        "end": "2021-02-26 00:00:00",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48"
      }
    ],
    "properties": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 1,
        "property_id": 7,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27",
        "property": {
          "id": 7,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "title": "Green",
          "slug": "green",
          "value": "#008000",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": 1,
          "parent_id": null,
          "title": "Color",
          "slug": "color",
          "value": null,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 1,
        "property_id": 20,
        "parent_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-22 19:43:27",
        "property": {
          "id": 20,
          "parent_id": 3,
          "title": "1 TB",
          "slug": "1-tb",
          "value": "1 TB",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": null,
          "title": "Store Capacity",
          "slug": "store-capacity",
          "value": null,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 2,
        "property_id": 7,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "property": {
          "id": 7,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "title": "Green",
          "slug": "green",
          "value": "#008000",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": 1,
          "parent_id": null,
          "title": "Color",
          "slug": "color",
          "value": null,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 2,
        "property_id": 12,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "property": {
          "id": 12,
          "parent_id": 2,
          "title": "L",
          "slug": "l",
          "value": "Large",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "parent_id": null,
          "title": "Size",
          "slug": "size",
          "value": null,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_detail_id": 2,
        "property_id": 17,
        "parent_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-24 19:26:48",
        "property": {
          "id": 17,
          "parent_id": 3,
          "title": "64 GB",
          "slug": "64-gb",
          "value": "64 GB",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        "parent": {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": null,
          "title": "Store Capacity",
          "slug": "store-capacity",
          "value": null,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know the properties that user added because it is dynamic. So I'm reaching the properties like this.

```
function makeQueryString() {
    function keyValues(idPref) {
        var key = idPref,
            values = $('#' + idPref + ' input[id^="' + idPref + '"]').map(function() {
                if (this.value !== this.defaultValue || this.checked !== this.defaultChecked) {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }).get().join(',');

        return key && values.length ? key + '=' + values : '';
    }

    return $('form#property-filter span[id]').map(function(){
        let keyValue = keyValues(this.id);
        if (keyValue != ''){
            return keyValue;
        }
    }).get().join('&');
}
```

**Properties Result;**
id of properties with name

```
color=6,7&store-capacity=15,16,17&ram=21,22,23
```

**EDIT**

The main problem is make a filter using property result.
For example when user select Red And Blue color and click filter button it will return color=6,7 and I should filter my json data with this and bring only if include color 6 or 7. At the same time if user select red, 64GB, 128GB then it should return only if red color with 64 or 128.

***I tried so far;***

```
function filterProducts(prop) {
    // prop = color=6,7&store-capacity=15,16,17&ram=21,22
    prop = prop.split('&');
    let x = [];
    for (i=0; i<prop.length; i++){
        x.push(prop[i].split('='));
    }
    let newProductsArr = [];
    for (p=0; p<products.length; p++) {
        for (k=0; k< products[p].properties.length; k++){
            for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
                if(x[i][0] === products[p].properties[k].parent.slug){
                    let ids = x[i][1].split(',');
                    for (g=0; g<ids.length; i++){
                        if (products[p].properties[k].property_id === ids[g]){
                            newProductsArr.push(products[p])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say "It Returns", do you mean "this is what I'd like to get"?  Where does the JSON data come from?  I don't see any JSON here.  Once you have the JSON eval-ed into an object, you can just iterate through obj[0].properties and pullout x.property.id where x.parent.id == 'color' or 'store-capacity'.

Comment: I mean i have json data coming from controller. And I'm reading the  products json like this -> {{ @json($products) }}. I want to filter this data when user click filter button. Whenever user click filter button it will return what property selected on properties. For example red and 2GB ram. This selection would return red=1&ram=8.

Comment: Then you do just what I said.  You do `for( prop in obj[0].properties )`, check that `prop.parent.id` equals the property name, and pull out `prop.property.id` as your number.

Comment: It can not work. Let me show what i tried so far may that help me to give better explanation.